# Excel #VALUE error when using FIND function

Tags: excel

I am extracting all text before a comma and am using this formula:

```
=LEFT(F2,(FIND(",",F2,1)-1))
```

Some cells do not contain commas, and for these I am getting a #VALUE error.

I would like the original text to show up in the error cells, and have been trying to incorporate `IFERROR`/`ISERROR` or `IF` functions- but now sure how to add to existing formula so that the original text will show up.

Example:

`Red Barn, 20` (my formula correctly shows "`Red Barn`")

`Red Bard` (my formula shows `#VALUE`- when I would like "Red Barn" to be shown)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get this error because `FIND` cannot find the required character in the text F2. You can use an `IFERROR()` around this `FIND()-1`:

```
=LEFT(F2,IFERROR(FIND(",",F2,1)-1,LEN(F2)))
```

If there's no `,`, then it will make `LEN(F2)` will will result in the whole text.

Also, you can omit the last `1` in `FIND` since that's the default value.

```
=LEFT(F2,IFERROR(FIND(",",F2)-1,LEN(F2)))
```